# latex-mode-hook or LaTeX-mode-hook?

Tags: latex, hooks

When I did some clean up of my Emacs init file, I discovered that I had used both

```el
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook ...)
```

and

```el
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook ...)
```

What is the difference between `LaTeX-mode-hook` and `latex-mode-hook`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`LaTeX-mode-hook` is used by AUCTeX's LaTeX mode.

`latex-mode-hook` is used by Emacs' built-in latex mode.

Comment: Thanks! I was not that there were two different LaTeX modes..

Comment: Here is a link that could be of interest: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/agxALwrTUI8